# Dojo List Text Box automatic delimiter

Tags: dojo, xpages

When we started using a Dojo List Text Box in one of our applications, I came across the problem, that this Dojo control seems to have a built in delimiter, automatically splitting every String that contains a comma into extra array items.

A code to verify this behaviour:

```
<xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox1"></xe:djextListTextBox><xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker1" for="djextListTextBox1">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:simpleValuePicker>
                <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[11111
222,22
33333]]></xe:this.valueList>
            </xe:simpleValuePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:valuePicker>
```

I managed to resolve the situation by manually defining another delimiter

```
 multipleSeparator="|"
```

which seems to overwrite the default delimiter, but I still would be very interested in verification of this finding and experts' tips on how to handle this control properly for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it uses "," as the default delimiter.

It is defined in the dojo widget source code of `_ListTextBox.js` (in com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls package, `\resources\web\extlib\dijit` folder. This is the base widget for several components (e.g. ListTextBox, NameTextBox, etc.) and the multiple item seperator (msep) defaults to ",".

Basically, these components keep value in a hidden inputbox and submit that value. Internally, they convert the submitted value into a vector and store into the data binding. So as long as you don't have the declared delimiter in your value list, you may use any delimiter.

One problem I had is `\n`, because I experienced some problems in the past. Using ";" or "," is no problem with ListTextBox. However, NameTextBox doesn't work with any delimiter other than ",". No big deal, because it's only name elements. If you use ",", this component keeps values correctly but does not render well.